# To use notifyListeners() like a setState()

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm making a timer with a Flutter. Initially, I used statefulwidget with setState, but currently I moved timer code to use the provider.

The problem now is that when I used setState time worked well, but when I used notifyListeners() the time didn't go immediately, how Can I use notifyListeners() to change the time like setState?

setState code

```
        _StartTimer() {
      startTime = formatted;
      start = new DateTime.now();
      start = elapsedTime > 0
          ? start.subtract(Duration(seconds: elapsedTime))
          : start;
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
          if (time > elapsedTime) {
            elapsedTime = DateTime.now().difference(start).inSeconds;
          } else {
            endTime = formatter.format(new DateTime.now());
            time = pomodoroTime * 60;
            elapsedTime = 0;
            ++count;
            _animationController.reverse();
            timer.cancel();
            bottomSheet();
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

notifyListeners() code

```
StartTimer() {
        startTime = formatted;
        start = new DateTime.now();
        start = elapsedTime > 0
            ? start.subtract(Duration(seconds: elapsedTime))
            : start;
        timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
          if (time > elapsedTime) {
            elapsedTime = DateTime.now().difference(start).inSeconds;
          } else {
            endTime = formatter.format(new DateTime.now());
            time = pomodoroTime * 60;
            elapsedTime = 0;
            timer.cancel();
          }
          notifyListeners();
        });
      }
```

Comment: are you extending change notifier and adding the provider in the main class

Comment: Yes I solved the reason why timer didn't work is I set Provider.of listen : false...